# Div auto height not working - CSS

Tags: css

I've a banner slider made entirely in CSS.
here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mPH4H/63/
I am trying to force the height of the div 'slider' to resize when you are scaling the browser. I know that it is currently set to 500px but auto for height does not work. The border is just to show the div outlines. I think that the issue is in a relation between the relative position of the container and absolute position of the other div's but I can't figure it out.

I am sorry if this is a dumb question. I've hard time finding solution for this as a beginner. Any help would be highly appreciated.

**HTML:**

```
<div class='slider'>
<div class='Bslide1'></div>
<div class='Bslide2'></div>
<div class='Bslide3'></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.slider {
max-width: 1920px;
height: 500px;
margin: 0 auto;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 5px;
border-color: tomato;
position: relative;
}

.Bslide1,.Bslide2,.Bslide3,.Bslide4,.Bslide5 {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;

}
.Bslide1 {
background: url(image1.png)no-repeat center;
background-size: contain;
animation:fade 8s infinite;
-webkit-animation:fade 8s infinite;
} 
.Bslide2 {
background: url(image2.png)no-repeat center;
background-size: contain;
animation:fade2 8s infinite;
-webkit-animation:fade2 8s infinite;
}
.Bslide3 {
background: url(image3.png)no-repeat center;
background-size: contain;
animation:fade3 8s infinite;
-webkit-animation:fade3 8s infinite;
}
@keyframes fade
{
0%   {opacity:1}
33.333% { opacity: 0}
66.666% { opacity: 0}
100% { opacity: 1}
}
@keyframes fade2
{
0%   {opacity:0}
33.333% { opacity: 1}
66.666% { opacity: 0 }
100% { opacity: 0}
}
@keyframes fade3
{
0%   {opacity:0}
33.333% { opacity: 0}
66.666% { opacity: 1}
100% { opacity: 0}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use vh instead of px for the height of your slider

```
.slider {
max-width: 1920px;
height: 60vh;
margin: 0 auto;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 5px;
border-color: tomato;
position: relative;
}

.Bslide2 {
background: url(image2.png)no-repeat center;
top: 60vh;
background-size: contain;
animation:fade2 8s infinite;
-webkit-animation:fade2 8s infinite;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment Yehuda but unfortunately this does not resolved my issue.

Comment: perhaps vw is what you need?

Comment: That's exactly what I need! Thank you very much Yehuda, I appreciate it.